# Convex hull of orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, orthogonal-matrices, convex-hulls, spectral-norm

Where can I find the proof of the fact that the convex hull of the set of orthogonal matrices is the set of matrices with norm not greater than one?

It is easy to show that a convex combination of orthogonal matrices has norm (I mean the norm as operators) not larger than $1$. The reverse seems quite tricky...

Comment: Maybe you would be interested in the generalization of this fact: the [Russo-Dye theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo%E2%80%93Dye_theorem). This is proved in most books that talk about C*-algebras. Davidson's book, for example. You can also look at [Popa's quantitative version](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.mmj/1029002561) of it, in free access.

Comment: Kyle A. Gallivan, P.-A. Absil, [Note on the convex hull of the Stiefel manifold](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ealuffi/archive/paper386.pdf), July 19, 2010.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Presumably the norm in question is the operator $2$-norm, i.e. the largest singular value. Now suppose $\|A\|\le1$. Consider the singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$, where $U,V$ are real orthogonal and $\Sigma=\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{s})$ for some $\mathbf{s}\in[0,1]^n$ is a diagonal matrix with entries between $0$ and $1$. Since products of orthogonal matrices are orthogonal, it suffices to show that $\Sigma$ is a convex combination of orthogonal matrices, but clearly, $\mathbf{s}$ is a convex combination of the extreme points $\mathbf{s}_1,\mathbf{s}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{s}_{2^n}$ of $\{-1,1\}^n$. Therefore $\Sigma$ is a convex combination of $\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{s}_1),\,\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{s}_2),\,\ldots,\,\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{s}_{2^n})$, which are real orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

I want to slightly extend the answer of @user1551 to the unitary case because --- although the proof idea stays the same --- in the complex case every contraction is the *arithmetic mean* of just **two** unitaries (cf. also page 42 of Bhatia's book *"Positive Definite Matrices"*, 2007).

> **Proposition.** Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ be given. If $\|A\|_{2\to 2}\leq 1$, then there exist $U_1,U_2\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ unitary such that $A=\frac12(U_1+U_2)$.

Here $\|\cdot\|_{2\to 2}$ denotes, as before, the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) with respect to the $2$-norm on $\mathbb C^n$, i.e. the largest singular value of the input.

*Proof.* As before the easiest way to show this is to use the singular value decomposition $A=U{\rm diag}(s_1,\ldots,s_n)V$ where $U,V$ are unitary and $s_1,\ldots,s_n\in[0,1]$.
With this we for each $j=1,\ldots,n$ define $$z_j^+:=s_j+i\sqrt{1-s_j^2}\qquad \quad z_j^-:=s_j-i\sqrt{1-s_j^2}\,,
$$
as well as
\begin{align*}
U_1&:=U{\rm diag}(z_1^+,\ldots,z_n^+)V\\
U_2&:=U{\rm diag}(z_1^-,\ldots,z_n^-)V\,.
\end{align*}
Obviously $|z_j^\pm|=1$ so $U_1,U_2$ are unitary as product of three unitaries, and $U_1+U_2=U{\rm diag}(2s_1,\ldots,2s_n)V=2A$.$\quad\square$