# Singular values of square orthogonal matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices

What are the singular values of an $n \times n$ square orthogonal matrix? 
How do we know that the set of all orthogonal matrices is convex? Is there an example?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, whether the first question can be answered. This is because SVD works by finding a right and a left orthogonal (rotation) matrix, which rotates the matrix in question to column resp row orthogonality. But the nxn orthogonal matrix is already row and column-orthogonal. Thus the SVD routine has no rotation-criterion.  I tried my implementation and could not come nearer to diagonality of the base matrix by my SVD-implementation.

Comment: ¿How do we know the set of all orthogonal matrices is convex? We do not know that, it is not even connected, hence not convex! (The determinant of an orthogonal matrix is $\pm 1$, and the continuous image of a connected set is connected, so by contraposition set of orthogonal matrices is not connected).

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are invertible square matrices, so their singular values are their eigenvalues.  Their eigenvalues are complex numbers whose norm (i.e. absolute value) is $1$, or in other words, they're all on the circle of unit radius centered at $0$ in the complex plane.  There's an easy way to prove that, and if I recalled instantly how it goes I'd post this as an answer.

Comment: Why do you think that the set of orthogonal matrices is convex? Take $Q\in O(n)$, then $-Q\in O(n)$, but zero matrix is not orthogonal.

Comment: Apologies. I mean, the set is non-convex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SVD of a matrix $A$ is $A = U \Sigma V^T$, where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is nonnegative real diagonal.

Now, let $X$ be orthogonal. Note that $X = U \Sigma V^T$, where $U := X$ is orthogonal, $\Sigma := {\rm I}$ is diagonal, and $V := {\rm I}$ is orthogonal. So, singular values are all equal to $1$.

Or, you can use the definition by which the singular values of $X$ are the absolute square roots of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$. In case of an orthogonal $X$, eigenvalues of $X^T X = {\rm I}$ are all equal to one, so the singular values of $X$ are all equal to $1$.

As for your second question, I don't think the statement is true. Let

$$X = {\rm I} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad Y = \begin{bmatrix} & 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

If the set of the orthogonal matrix is convex, then $Z := \frac{1}{2}(X+Y)$ is also orthogonal. But,

$$Z = \frac{1}{2}(X+Y) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

is singular, so it cannot be orthogonal. We can even check directly: $Z^T Z = Z \ne {\rm I}$.

You can find a topic on the convex hull of the set of orthogonal matrices [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434720/78926).

Comment: Thanks. I meant how to show an example that the set of all orthogonal matrices are non-convex?

Comment: @John Since there is a question mark at the end of your comment, but I already gave an example (and there is also one by TZakrevskiy in the comments above), is this still a question?

Comment: No it's not. Thanks for answering. My doubts are cleared.