# Polar set of orthogonal matrices set is nuclear norm ball

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, orthogonal-matrices, nuclear-norm

Reltated problems:
[Show that the dual norm of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158798/show-that-the-dual-norm-of-spectral-norm-is-nuclear-norm)
[Prove that the nuclear norm is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142540/proof-that-nuclear-norm-is-convex)

---

The set of orthogonal matrices is defined as:

$$\mathcal{O}(n) = \{X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:X^TX=I\}$$

The polar of $\mathcal{O}(n)$:

$$\mathcal{O}(n)^o = \{Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\langle Y,X\rangle\leq 1, \forall X\in \mathcal{O}(n)\}$$

i.e., the set of linear functionals that take value at most one on $\mathcal{O}(n)$.  The definition of polar cone is the general definition.

> How to prove the polar of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is the nuclear norm ball?
>   i.e. $$\mathcal{O}(n)^o = \{Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(Y)\leq 1\}$$

---

I try to  consider how to go to $\sum\sigma_i\leq1$ from $\langle Y,X\rangle=\text{tr}(YX)\leq 1$; however, I cannot find a way to break through.

By `user1551`'s suggestion:

Let $YX=U\Sigma V^T$, where $Y\in \mathcal{O}(n)^o, X\in \mathcal{O}(n)$.

By [Convex hull of orthogonal matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434720/convex-hull-of-orthogonal-matrices), **can I say**:

> $\|YX\|_2^2=\langle Y,X \rangle \leq 1$ so I get $\Sigma$'s diagonal elements $\in [0,1]^n$.   If this is true, how to say the SVD of $Y$, particularly $\Sigma(Y)$?

Note: $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the spectral norm (the largest singular value).

Comment: You should note that this is note the polar *cone*, but the polar *set*. The polar cone is defined with $\le 0$ (instead of $\le 1$) and, as the name suggests, it is a cone.

Comment: Does the boxed statement follow directly from singular value decomposition?

Comment: @gerw I modify it.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 1):

I will call $\mathcal{A} = \{Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\langle Y,X\rangle\leq 1, \forall X\in \mathcal{O}(n)\}$ and $\mathcal{B} = \{Y\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(Y)\leq 1\}$, denote the nuclear norm by $\|\cdot\|_1$ and the operator norm by $\|X\|_{\infty}$ (the indexing comes from viewing them as special cases of the Schatten norms).

**Part 1: $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$**

This direction follows from the Hölder's inequality. Let $Y \in \mathcal{B}$ and $X \in \mathcal{O}(n)$ then by Hölder's inequality we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle Y, X \rangle &\leq \|Y\|_1 \|X\|_{\infty}\\
&= \|Y\|_1\\
&\leq 1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus $Y \in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$.

**Part 2:** $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$

This direction is a little more tricky. To solve it we need the following lemma which gives a variational characterization of the nuclear norm.

**Lemma**: Let $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ then
$$
\|Y\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i(Y) = \max_{X \in \mathcal{O}(n)} \langle Y,X\rangle.U
$$
*Proof*$\quad$ Consider the singular value decomposition $Y = UDV$ where $U,V \in \mathcal{O}(n)$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix containing the singular values of $Y$. Then let $X = UV$ and we see
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle Y, X\rangle &= \mathrm{Tr}[Y^T X] \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[V^T D U^T UV] \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[VV^T D U^T U] \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}[D] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(Y).
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus $\sum_i \sigma_i(Y) \leq \max_{X \in \mathcal{O}(n)} \langle Y,X\rangle$. The other inequality follows directly from the Hölder's inequality used in **Part 1**, i.e. $\langle Y, X\rangle \leq \|Y\|_1$ for any $X \in \mathcal{O}(n)$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Now the result follows fairly quickly. Given $Y \in \mathcal{A}$ we know $\langle Y , X \rangle \leq 1$ for all $X \in \mathcal{O}(n)$. However, from the above lemma we also know that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(Y) &= \max_{X \in \mathcal{O}(n)} \langle Y,X\rangle \\
&\leq 1
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus $Y \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ and we are done!